# How to correctly specify gitignore files?

Tags: git, react-native, github, gitignore

Im using github desktop. I have a project on git in react native. I want to have my own branch where I can save all my `/ios` and `/android` folders and another branch for me and my mate with just `app.js ...etc` files without `ios` and `android` folders. How should I organise my gitignore folders correctly? 
Is there a rule that masters gitignore should always exist more information than its other branches?
I added /ios and /android for masters gitignore, why it keeps deleting them from my pc?

Comment: I think you are missing the point that `.gitignore` is a tracked file too - it's not necessarily the same on all branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides me thinking, that having 2 projects on 2 branches in the same repo is a good idea.

All you need to do is create the `.gitignore` files for each branch and commit them.

When you switch branches the `.gitignore` of the respective branch will also be checked out.

If you have files you want to ignore but not add them to `.gitignore` then add them to `.git/info/exclude`